# Find closest number in a circular array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array:

```
np.arange(1, 366)
```

I have 2 values: `355` and `129`. I want to find which one of them is closest value to a number within that array, say `36`.

In this case, the answer will be `355` since I want the array to roll around i.e. `365 is followed by`1`.

I can do this by using multiple if else conditions, is there a more pythonic solution?

Comment: Can you share your code, too (the solution that you tried)

Comment: If this is about sequential numbers (and this is what your question says, but probably not what you mean), you could use the modulo operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
aa=np.arange(1, 366)
bb=np.array([355, 136, 155,154 ])
c=36

def short(bb,c):
    x0= np.min(np.abs(bb-c))
    x1= np.min(np.abs(366-bb+c))  
    if x0<x1:
        return bb[np.argmin(bb-c)]
    else: 
        return bb[np.argmin(366-bb+c)]


bb=np.array([355, 136, 155,154 ])
print short(bb,c)

bb=np.array([355, 136, 155,154,38])
print short(bb,c)
```

output:

```
355
38
```

Answer (score 2):

I utilized Polar coordinates mathematics to solve this:

[image]

```
import numpy as np

array = [355,129]
target = 36

def distance(list_of_points, target):
    options = {}
    for point in list_of_points:
        distance = np.sqrt(1+1-(2*1)*(np.cos(np.deg2rad(target - point))))
        print distance
        if point not in options:
            options[distance] = point

    return options[min(options)]

print distance(array,target)
```

Output:

```
355
```

Comment: He is not referring to a 2D geometric circle , I think, but to a vector, that wraps around in terms of positions. Interestingly the geometric idea works nevertheless :)

Comment: @roadrunner66 I was simply inspired by circle to use geometry :D